# Overflowing text does not wrap

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a very long text but it doesn't wrap to next line. I have searched for the solution on the internet and found that `Flexible` element could resolve it, but when I try to put it anywhere, all the elements just disappear. I couldn't fix it so I am here to ask your help.

[image]
[image]

```dart
List<Widget> children = payload['data'].map<Widget>((element) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(children: [
          Text(
              element['display_name'] +
                  ' - ' +
                  (element['dist'].toDouble() / 1000).toStringAsFixed(2) +
                  'km',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 16))
        ]),
        Row(children: [
          Text('test')
        ]),
        Row(children: [
          Text(
              'loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed ')
        ]),
        Divider(height: 12, thickness: 2)
      ],
    );
  }).toList();
```

**EDIT:**

@Ravindra S. Patil's answer solved the issue, now everything wraps nice and clean.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your **Text** inside **Flex** or **Expanded** like below:

```
Expanded(
child: Text(
              'loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed loooooooong text, very long indeed '),
),
```

Comment: Never thought it would be that easy, solved the issue.