# Flutter Text inside Container doesn't expand to second line [Chat Bubble]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a messenger app but couldn't find solution for this,

**Issue:**
The container Widget doesn't expand for long text inside Text Widget

```
-Container()

   |
    --> Text()
```

**What I Tried:**

I Tried Flexible Widget inside container over the Text Widget but that doesn't work. Flex doesn't work inside Container.

**Error : **

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 38 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Row
lib\views\chatScreen.dart:201
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[image]

**My Code :**

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isMine;
  String message;
  MessageBubble(this.isMine, this.message);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            isMine ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isMine ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
            ),
            child: 
              child: Text(
                message,
                textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.parent,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ), 
        ]);
  }
}
```

**Code Tried With Flexible: (Doesn't Work)**

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isMine;
  String message;
  MessageBubble(this.isMine, this.message);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            isMine ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isMine ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
            ),
            child: Flexible(
              child: Text(
                message,
                textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.parent,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

**Result with Flexible or Expanded:**

[image]

**What I really want?:**

The ChatBubble should not be equal to size of the screen.
Like the Image Below.

[image]

Comment: Add your Widget inside Expanded or Flexible refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210)  hope its help to you

Comment: Flexible and Expanded Both gives this Error : ``Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget``

Comment: can you tell me where to use Expanded or Flexible widget

Comment: Dear @RavindraS.Patil I want to use to over  Text() Which is Inside Container().

Comment: can you add your updated code?

Comment: check my answer hope its help to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you need to specify the min width to the container and you are all set.
Test this:

```
return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            isMine ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          IntrinsicWidth(
              child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 14),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isMine ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: isMine ? Radius.circular(20) : Radius.circular(0),
                bottomLeft: isMine ? Radius.circular(20) : Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: isMine ? Radius.circular(10) : Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: isMine ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              message,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 16),
            ),
          )),
        ]);
```

Comment: Thank you Mam, The Max width to the container did it

Answer (score 0):

Let me save you time, you can use Flutter Chat Bubble, Get it here on [pub](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_basic_chat_bubble)

The library got you covered for text wrap and the rest

Below is a sample

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below answer hope its help to you I have try your code and I think your problem is solved, Just Wrap your **Container** inside **Flexible or Expanded Widget**

```
  Expanded(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 14),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
              "hfduasudfufabsydsxfssahfduasudfufabsydsxfssahfduasudfufabsydsxfssahfduasudfufabsydsxfssahfduasudfufabsydsxfssa"),
        ),
      ),
```

Result of your Screen -> [image]

Comment: your solution take full screen width of the device. I have edited the question please check the image of what result i really want.

Comment: Try to use In **IntrinsicWidth()** widget refer documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) and use container width is MediaQuery [refer here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:
          sendByMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
              bottomLeft: sendByMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(24),
              topRight: Radius.circular(24),
              bottomRight: sendByMe ? Radius.circular(24) : Radius.circular(0),
            ),
            color: sendByMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
          child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: 60.w,
              ),
              child: Text(
                message,
              )),
        )
      ],
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah this could use more explanation, but the container constraints helped me a lot - so thanks :-)